# Proof the following trig series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

Prove that
$$\frac{ \sin x}{ \cos x}+\frac{\sin2x}{\cos^{2}x}+\frac{\sin3x}{\cos^{3}x}+\cdots+\frac{\sin nx}{\cos^{n}x}=\cot x-\frac{\cos(n+1)x}{\sin x \cos^{n}x}$$

I am not necessarily looking for a solution to this question but a way to approach it, i.e. when I get a question like this in the test what should I do, what should I look for?

Answer (score 4):

$\textbf{HINT}:$

$\text{Use the fact that}$
$$\cos((n+1)x) = \cos(nx) \cos(x) - \sin(nx) \sin(x)$$
$\text{and obtain}$
$$\sin(nx) \sin(x) = \cos(nx) \cos(x) - \cos((n+1)x)$$
$\text{to conclude that}$
$$\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{\cos^n(x)} = \dfrac{\cos(nx)}{\sin(x) \cos^{n-1}(x)} - \dfrac{\cos((n+1)x)}{\sin(x) \cos^{n}(x)}$$

> $\text{Do a telescopic summation to get the result.}$

Comment: @AlexanderJones Use the formula $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a \sin b$ with $a=nx$, $b=x$.

Comment: @Alexander Jones: Here is the general trick/idea: To prove $$\sum_{k=1}^n f_k = S_n$$ try to show that $$f_k = S_k - S_{k-1}$$
and now let the telescopic summation do the job for you.

Comment: It's very easy to do once I am given a hint... :(

Comment: I'd say that Induction will be more natural, since you don't have to guess what the $S_n$ is

Comment: But induction takes a lot of time and some questions in the IMO can't be done by induction.

Comment: @CalvinLin What I have written has hidden induction.

Comment: @AlexanderJones The induction step is immediate (and the base case is obvious). So what if there are questions that can't be done by induction? There are lots of IMO questions that can't be done by trial and error, or trying small cases, or considering the convex hull. Does that mean that such techniques are pointless?

Comment: @CalvinLin Ok, I will consider induction from now on. Thank you.